# google calendar api v2 for php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

Does anyone have an API library for google calendar API, version 2? - http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

There is a zend library here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html but it is based on version 1 of the api.

A simple google search has not yielded any results: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=calendar+api+2+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.0 of the API is a lot more restricted in the amount of languages available and PHP is not one of them. You can use version 1 which still works perfectly well, or you can switch to one of the languages where v2 is available, like python.